# How can I prevent a Highcharts Sankey chart form converting a small link into a circle (without setting a higher minLinkWidth value)?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sankey-diagram

I think this addition of circles in place of small links is a new behavior because I didn't encounter it a few weeks ago. However, I definitely do not want small circles in my Sankey charts. I would expect that the "width threshold" for the decision to switch from a bar to a circle would be added to the API with a descriptive name such as "displayCircleLinkWidthThreshold" (which I could set to zero to disable circles); however, I didn't see a parameter like this in the documentation.

Did I miss it?

Is this threshold exposed under some other name or simply hard coded?

Are there other techniques by which one can ascertain and then override the default behavior without creating fragile code?

Also, is there a similar threshold for the decision to display / not display the label text?

P.S> Please do not reply to tell me about "minLinkWidth". It's not the solution.
P.P.S> If there's a sufficiently low-friction path worked out for making one-time contributions to the code base, I'd be happy to take a crack at implementing these simple feature tweaks myself. But I'd want to see a document or a video that explains the steps really well before I invest time into this.

[image: Sankey chart "link" being converted into a circle]

Comment: Hi @phil1008, This is probably a bug in the newest Highcharts and it is related to a different calculation of `borderWidth`. As a workaround, you can set `borderRadius: 0`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r3y2xeha/ Related thread on GitHub: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/18956